# The concept of center of mass behind dropping water from a faucet?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, mass

> Water, dripping at a constant rate from a faucet, falls to the ground. At any instant there are
>   many drops in the air between the faucet and the ground. Where does the center of mass of
>   the drops lie relative to the halfway point between the faucet and the ground? (a) Above it
>   (b) Below it (c) Exactly at the halfway point

When I looked at this, I thought the answer is (b) below it since if the water drop and the ground are in a system, then the center of mass will be nearer to the heavier object, which is the ground. But when I looked up the answer it was (a) above it. Could you please explain why? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider just a *single* water drop. During its accelerated motion downward (its decent), does it spend more of its time *above* the halfway point, *below* the halfway point, or does it spend an *equal* amount of time in each?

Answering that question may help you.

Comment: I see.. But does it only apply to constant rate of dripping? If the dripping rate is increasing/decreasing will the solution be different? P.S: Thanks for the edit!

Comment: rate is surely independent of the fact @BMS is talking about, rate relates multiple drops but gravity determines speed and position of  a single drop

Comment: At any given *time* the center of mass could be anywhere. The result above is valid for time *averages*.